# Oracle sql select query where primary key is random

Tags: sql, oracle, select, random

I have an oracle table which is being filled with voice call detail records. I would like to select the data  from this table and transfer it to another database every 20 mins. The id for the call record is created when the call is started but the calls are only added to the cdr record table upon completion of the call, which results in the rows in the table being random entered. I would like to use  a query which selected all the data that is newer than the last extracted row from the previous query result.

For example based on the table below if the previous query extracted the. Rows up to id 24 the new query would extracted rows 54 , 6 and 53

```
Id.          CLI.       CLD
7.           1000.      2000
2.           1021.      2031
24.          1032.      2035
54.          1045.      2053
6.           1065.      2035
53.          1000.      2032
```

Thanks

John

Comment: You may want to provide some more details, such as where the CLI/CLD numbers come from (times? ids? etc). Full table structures are most helpful.

Comment: Unless your record includes the timestamp for when it was inserted, or another key based on insertion time, Oracle has no reliable to tell you anything abput the order. Why the 20-minute window; why not use a built-in mechanism, or even a trigger? Also, I assume CLI is the originating number, and CLD is the destination number in your small sample? Is there a delay between the call ending and the data being inserted?

Comment: Hi Alex, there are multiple voice platforms which feed the data into this table, if there is a network outage the remote systems do a store and  then forwards the data when the network is restored.  This could result in the timestamp for new data  bein older than existing data. I havent used triggers before, can they be set to run every 20 mins?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the last accessed id as a variable -- say `v_id` -- then:

```
select cdr.*
from cdr
where cdr.cld > (select cdr2.cld from cdr cdr2 where cdr2 = :v_id);
```

This assumes that if two records are put in with the same time stamp for the end of the call, then they are both present in any extract.

It might be safer for you to devise a sequential number based on the end-time of the call and to use that instead of a time stamp.

Comment: thanks Gordon I will give try this when I get back too the office.